# Azure Data Factory Trigger Azure Notebook Failure

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am trying to execute the notebook via azure datafactory to Azure Databricks notebook but unable to success my ADF pipeline, if I run the azure databricks notebook separately on my pyspark scripts, there is no error but if run via the ADF pipeline, i am getting below like.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prophet'
>
> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 6 import pandas as pd
> 7 import pyspark.pandas as ps
> ----> 8 from prophet import Prophet
> 9 from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType, TimestampType, DateType, IntegerType
> 10

[image]

I am not sure, if we installed everting in ADB cluster but throwing the error in ADF pipeline. i tried to restart the cluster and all the possibility. Kindly provide your advice.

Comment: Are you using the same cluster for Notebook activity or new cluster?

Comment: I am using new job cluster. how do we handle to install while runtime to install my lib, even if i tried Append Libraries option to install to give the dfs lib file location but the cluster not taking or allow to install the lib

Comment: %pip install /dbfs/FileStore/jars/prophet/prophet-1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Python interpreter will be restarted.
Processing /dbfs/FileStore/jars/prophet/prophet-1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.0.0 in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from prophet==1.1) (3.4.2)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,

Comment: prophet==1.1) (3.4.2)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools-git/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))': /simple/setuptools-git/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and faced similar error.

[image]

To resolve this I Installed prophet PYPI library on cluster.

> go to your cluster >> libraries >> Install library >> PyPI >> Packge:"prophet" >> install

[image]

Now ADF executing Databricks notebook

[image]